# Text to speech not working on Head Unit and DHU

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-auto

I am trying to implement Text-to-speech in my android  auto app but unable to hear it on Desktop head unit. I have also tried it on Car Head unit but no luck.

below is the code i am using

```
 TextToSpeech tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
           t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        }
     }
  });
```

and on button click i am using

```
 tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

also tried to  turn OFF Bluetooth Headset as suggested in [xda forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android-auto/android-auto-general/android-auto-wont-read-text-messages-to-t3413950)
but still same issue.

Do i need to add any extra library like "gear.aar" to make it work for Auto as the code is in `CarActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

speak() method requires four parameters to execute the job
I solved this using below code

```
 tts.speak(readText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, ""+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

This is what should be done:

- be sure you call `tts.speak(...)` after TTS is initialized (return 0 - SUCCESS)
- turn off bluetooth on the computer